# How to export columns from different scrpits into a single csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple scripts, each of them have a Dataframe. I want to Export one column from each script/Dataframe into a single csv.

I can crate a csv from my "first" script with one column:

```
Vorhersagen = pd.DataFrame(columns=["solar_prediction"])
Vorhersagen["solar_prediction"] = Erzeugung["erzeugung_predicted"]
Vorhersagen.to_csv(r"H:/.../Vorhersagen_2017.csv")
```

Now i have a csv (called "Vorhersagen_2017") with the column "solar_prediction". But how can I add another column (from another script) to the same csv as a second column? (The columns have the same length)

Comment: Can you add the other column that you want before saving to csv?

Comment: I could, but i have at least 15 different scripts (=15 columns), These scripts use the same variables. So in the end i would have one gigantic script where i had to Change all variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to update the csv file by running different scripts. If this is the case then I would just read the file, append the new column and save the file again. Something like:

```
df=pd.read_csv('Vorhersagen_2017.csv',...)
df2=pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1) #df1 is the dataframe created by your second script
df2.to_csv(...)
```

Then you would have to run this iteratively in all your scripts.

However, I think is more efficient to import all your script as [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) in a main script and run them from there. From this main script you could easily concatenate the various columns and save them as a csv at once.

Comment: yes i wanted to update the csv file, thanks for your answer! Your method is working fine for mine project. The only thing I have to add is that after reading the existing csv there is a first column with Indices added (I'm not sure why), so you have to drop the first column before exporting the "new" csv. About modules: as a beginner I don't know much about that and at the moment i don't have the time to look into it

Comment: did you try using index_col=0 when reading the csv file? refer to pandas readcsv [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)